# Change Event (VBA Excel) It doesn't work when is calling for time stamp

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use the Worksheet Change Event in Excel VBA, but it doesn't seem to working how I thought it would.I am trying to stamp date+time in the column 4 when I do a change in the column 2. But, it doesn't work. Also, I am trying (At the same time) to protect the worksheet but, is off. I will appreciate somebody can give me orientation to solve these issues.

Attach the event(Let me know my error, please) Thanks.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="avalon"
        If Target.Column = 2 Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Cells(Target.Row, 4).Value = Date + Time
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="avalon"
End Sub
```

[Pic of the report to solve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5WYK.jpg)

[VBA Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZQLt.jpg)

Comment: "But, it doesn't work." is not a very good problem description.  Your code works for me but, if you give us at least some clue as to what isn't working for you, we might be able to suggest ways to fix your situation.

Comment: Where in your code are you defining Time?

Comment: Hello. In this case, I am looking that the time will be stamped in column E. –

Comment: I added a link with a shot or pic that shows the report that I am pretending to add the stamp time in column "E".